# ROS, opencv3 and CMake - unable to remove the library

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros, opencv3.0

**Working environment:**

- Kubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
- ROS Indigo (up-to-date, full desktop install)
- OpenCV 2.4.8

For some unknown reason I decided to install the **ros-indigo-opencv3** package which I regretted almost immediately due to the fact I also have the default version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 - OpenCV 2.4.8.

At first I noticed that QtCreator was warning me of possible incompatibility between 2.4.8 and 3.0.0 when I was building my CMake project (you can see the CMakeLists.txt at the end of this post) using only

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Then the errors started flowing about some missing reference around the cv::stereoSGBM module. There seems to be some change in the namespaces or whatever and the library I am using uses the 2.x branch of OpenCV (found that the hard way obviously :D) hence I told myself - I guess I will remove the above mentioned ROS package for OpenCV 3.0.0 and stick with the 2.4.8.

After uninstalling that package it all went bananas. Even though in CMakeLists.txt of my project I explicitly pointed version 2.4.8. to be used

```
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.8 REQUIRED)
```

upon launching my node with roslaunch died immediately with the following error:

> .../pmd_nano_node: error while loading shared libraries: **libopencv_highgui.so.3.0**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Huh...Okay...I checked if something has been left on my system (bad package maybe, which was unable to install and accordingly install properly?). For my surprise upon calling **locate** and piping the result with grep

```
user:~$ locate libopencv | grep 3.0
```

I got

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0
...

(basically all opencv libs)
```

So something was left there after all (with something I mean everything :D). However imagine my surprise when I **cd**-ed to the **/opt/ros/indigo/lib/** and found NOT A SINGLE file even remotely related to OpenCV let alone OpenCV 3.0.0.

Using **pkg-config** returns what I am expecting at least:

```
user:~$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/usr/include/opencv
user:~$ pkg-config --libs opencv
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so ...
-lopencv_calib3d ...
```

Note: I still don't know why **--cflags** never shows the **opencv2** include folder (opencv2 as argument is not recognized by pkg-config)

Further investigation made me re-run my CMakeLists.txt for my project with the **3.0.0** version as requirement and indeed CMake now complains that only **2.4.8** is found. For what reason though the application tries to get the 3.0.0 version of OpenCV's shared libs remains to be seen.

Any advice or someone who has encountered such problem before?

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pmd_nano)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -fpermissive -Wno-deprecated -Wno-sign-compare")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g -Wall")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "-pg")

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_msgs
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS highgui imgproc)
# Do NOT use OpenCV 3.0.0 or all hell will break loose. Package incompatilibity will be a fascinating thing to deal with...

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES pmd_nano
 CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport pcl_conversions pcl_msgs pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs uvc_camera
 DEPENDS
   system_lib # Boost PCL OpenCV
   boost_system
   PCL
   opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(pmd_nano
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/pmd_nano_node.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(pmd_nano_node
    src/pmd_nano_node.cpp
    src/ColorCamera.cpp
    src/DepthCamera.cpp
    src/PMDNano.cpp
)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(pmd_nano_node pmd_nano_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node boost_system)
link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node pthread)

target_link_libraries(pmd_nano_node ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libpmdaccess2.so)


#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_pmd_nano.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

**EDIT:**

Running **sudo updatedb** at least resolved the **locate** issue. The error during runtime is still present though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. It seemed that my workspace was a mess because of the removal of the package. So after I deleted **devel** and **build** followed by a quick **catkin_make** it runs fine now.

Comment: This is always the first thing I do, if there is something strange in the catkin build (in fact, I have to do this quite often...). I am not sure if it is a cmake problem or something special about catkin but it seems that there are some auto-generated files that are not updated automatically if the environment changes.

Comment: Lately I have been cleaning the damn workspace so often that I totally thought I had done this. XD As for whether it's a catkin or cmake problem - I think it's the first since CMake itself immediately detected that 3.0.0 was no longer available. Although catkin uses CMake it also has plenty of extra stuff in there. Would be nice if they change this behaviour to be honest. Not the first time I've spent so much time dealing with an issue that shouldn't have been there in the first place.