# linking issue with opencv and ros indigo while trying to install vision_opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, robotics, vision

Hi my question is of two folds.
First, I am confused as why there are opencv3 and OpenCV-3.1.0-dev packages is in /opt/ros/indigo/share as i have read that opencv 2.4.8 is the default version of ROS indigo.

Also, I have opencv 2.4.13 version installed on ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo, I want to use opencv for vision part for my project and for that i tried to install vision_opencv package from source. However when I try to build the package using catkin_make following error occurs

similar question is asked here [ROS, opencv3 and CMake - unable to remove the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762923/ros-opencv3-and-cmake-unable-to-remove-the-library)

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/image_geometry)
```

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake:183 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_xobjdetect" references the file

```
 "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect3.so.3.1.0"
```

but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

- The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
- An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
- The installation package was faulty and contained

  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (include)
  vision_opencv/image_geometry/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hemang/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hemang/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

---

What I dont understand is why is it trying to link with Opencv3 when system does not have opencv3 installed or ROS indigo comes with opencv3 now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I figured it out so in the CMakeLists.txt files of both cv_bridge and image_geometry, `find package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` 
should be `find package (OpenCV 2.4.13 REQUIRED)` . This is in my case as I have OpenCV 2.4.13 installed, one can replace it with any version one is using.